# Contar valores consecutivos en R

Tags: r, contador

Quiero saber en cuántos meses consecutivos NO hay valor nulo. Ejemplo de mis dt "datos":

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mes | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| Valor | 10 | NA | 5 | 6 | 9 | NA |
| Recuento | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 |

He probado con esta sentencia y da un resultado pero no es lo que yo busco:

```r
datos$Recuento<-sequence(rle(datos$Valor)$lengths)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar algo así:

```
no_nas <- !is.na(datos$Valor)
sequence(rle(no_nas)$lengths) * no_nas
```

La secuencia se regenera con cada aparición de un `NA`, la única cosa que faltaría es que el valor para el mes con `NA` sea 0 y no 1, por lo que finalmente multiplicamos por `no_nas` para lograrlo.

Comment: Ha funcionado :) Espero que sea usted profesor, si no el mundo está perdiendo un gran talento.